# Missing second array data using importrange in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to join two columns of data from two separate sheets. The first range appears fine, but the second briefly shows "loading" but is over written by the fist range of data. I have attached an [example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZHOMHCKisEqu0TpqsKXROtbOBG2ZjRJsANlgOWZOjU/edit?usp=sharing) Here is the formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet2!A1:A; Sheet3!A1:A})`

In this example, the data from Sheet3 is not appearing. My assumption is that it is because the range is dynamic (I don't know how much data will be in each column).

Comment: How about this? put "=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet2!A1:A & Sheet3!A1:A})" on A1 of Sheet1. I'm sorry if misunderstanding.

Comment: That combines the data into the cells. looking for the data from sheet2 to be retrieved and then the data from sheet3 to be added onto the data--all in one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you need to sort your arrays OR filter out the blanks - it basically tends to only include the second array below the rest of the rows of the first one, including blank rows

if order of the data `DOESN'T` matter to you, you can simply wrap the entire function with a final `SORT`.

```
=sort(ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet2!A1:A; Sheet3!A1:A}))
```

[image]

If order `DOES` matter, you can use this function:

```
={FILTER(Sheet2!A1:A,LEN(Sheet2!A1:A)>1);FILTER(Sheet3!A1:A,LEN(Sheet3!A1:A)>1)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following:
`=QUERY({Sheet2!A1:A; Sheet3!A1:A}, "where Col1 is not null and Col1 <> ''")`

filtering out the blanks prevented it from overwriting the data from the second range, I presume